# How do I create an htaccess redirect for multiple directories

Tags: regex, linux, .htaccess

I have to create a htaccess redirect for multiple image directories within a path to a root level image directory. The paths all have a variable within them though, in my case a directory named after a city/state...

We have a number of mini sites within our corp site, each mini site has its own image directory: `.../images/u/whatever.jpg`

Examples:

> root/store/local/birmingham-al/images/u/
>
> root/store/local/mongomery-al/images/u/
>
> root/store/local/nashville-tn/images/u/

I need a quick redirect that will tell the server to use the new shared image dir, instead of having images served from each of the `/images/u/`

All server requests should redirect image requests to:

> root/imagecdn

How can I do it so I only effect images in those /images/u/ directories?

I suck at regex but I'm certain it can be done. We need this as a quick fix instead of manually changing 1000+ paths.

Answer (score 0):

Does this regexp satisfy your needs?

```
/^.*/images/u(.*)$/gm
```

And the replacement string is `root/imagecdn$1`.

[Example](http://regexr.com?31qal)